# Typecheck in creating typescript npm package

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, node-modules

I am creating nodemodules with typescript , but i don't know how to type check input data's passed in typescript from nodejs js file  . If no way there what is advantage of creating node modules with typescript instead of js

Adding some code for better understanding

```
In my package index.ts 
export class SampleSDK{

    name:String ;
    constructor(name:String){
      this.name = name;
    }   

    getName(){
        return this.name;
    }


}
in index.js 

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var SampleSdk  = require("sample-sdk");
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  let  fdConnectSDK = new SampleSdk.SampleSDK(1000);
  console.log(fdConnectSDK.getName()); // this is printing 1000 instead i expect it should throw error
  res.send("HELLO")

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you give a specific example? TypeScript's advantages go way beyond input data sanitization, in fact run-time type checking is not a feature or goal of TS.

Comment: You should create (by your own or let ts compiler create) d.ts files. These files publish to your npm module as well so when someone download your module they can use it with types

Comment: If you are consuming module created with TypeScript in a JavaScript file (index.js in your example), of course there is no way to use type info because you are not running TypeScript. You are running JavaScript.